# Is there a way to have the C preprocessor change which STL implementation I'm using?

Tags: c++, stl, c-preprocessor

I have code in C++ along the lines of

```
#include<vector>

std::vector<double> foo;
```

I need to compile this code for an embedded platform which uses a custom implementation of STL called [uSTL](http://ustl.sourceforge.net/). Using it requires `#include`ing a `ustl.h` header file and [all STL classes are defined in another namespace](http://www.ecos.sourceware.org/docs-latest/ref/using-ustl-library.html). The above snippet should therefore become

```
#include<ustlh.>

ustl::vector<double> foo;
```

I don't want to modify the source code because it is library code used by other non-embedded applications. I was thinking of using the C preprocessor to transform `#include<vector>` to `#include<ustl.h>` but that seems to be impossible (macro names must be valid identifiers).

Is there another way to have the C preprocessor do this? Or is there another way that would not imply modifying the original source code?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to do something like:

```
#ifdef USE_USTL
#include <ustl.h>
using ustl::vector;
#else
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#endif

vector<double>  foo;
```